# How to develop custom widget plug-in in Qt?

Tags: qt

I want to create custom plug-in which can be dragged from designer.The plugin must be container so user can drag and drop other custom plug-in into container plugin.

Answer (score 2):

After designing your widget, in order to add it into Qt Creator you will need to subclass from `QDesignerCustomWidgetInterface` and implement its interface. ([See documentation](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/designer-creating-custom-widgets.html))

All are matter of copy and paste. You can use the Qt Creator's wizard, "Qt Custom Designer Widget". It will generate subclass, fill it with information given by you and generate code.

Then you should compile and install your widgets. The output is a shared library (a `dll` in windows or a `.so` in linux). You should copy the compiled library to designer's plugin path. for me, plugins are in `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt4/plugins/designer/`. Also if you've installed Qt Creator with SDK or stand-alone installer, you can do the same.

For container widgets, just implement `bool QDesignerCustomWidgetInterface::isContainer()` member function in your subclass and return a `true` from it. Also the wizard will ask you if you want to create a container widget or not ;)